# Unread email count next to account name

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to somehow show the number of unread emails from inbox next to the account?
At the moment this number is only shown next to the folder.

Atm I have to go through every single one of them, expand, check for emails, collapse and go to the next one.

[image: Outlook with many accounts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, you can't put the number next to the account.

But what you can do, is use the favorites bar.

Right-click the inbox folder for every account, and choose Add to favorites.

In the favorites bar at the top, all inboxes will show under eachother, and because the folder name Inbox is the same, it automatically appends the email address behind it. It will show unread messages there natively.

You can also do this for other folders. This is handy if you use rules to automatically move new emails to a specific folder. Putting them in your favorites too will allow you to see new emails for them as well.

Comment: Thx, I'm already doing this as a workaround. But it's not really great. When I want to move a message I have to search the correct account and expand it. Would be better if the corresponding account was focused on automatically.
But thx for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Favorites is the best alternatives as mentioned. Moreover, I think this feature can be archived by third-party tools or add-ins for Outlook. You can go to the MS feedback portal to submit a request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).